# Is there any way to delete selected item from listbox using Delete key?

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

I want to delete selected item from list box when Delete key is pressed.
Actually in my userform I have a listbox which shows data from a worksheet and I have a "Delete" command button that deletes entire matching row from worksheet and then listbox updates. But I wanted to do same thing using physical Delete key of keyboard.
I searched a lot on internet but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub ListBox1_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    
    If KeyCode = 46 Then
        With Me.ListBox1
            If .ListIndex <> -1 Then
                If MsgBox("Delete current item?" & vbCrLf & .Value, vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Delete entry") = vbYes Then
                    .RemoveItem (.ListIndex)
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
    
End Sub
```